# Drupal 7 soundcloud file field only shown in Preview not in Full Preview

Tags: drupal-7, soundcloud

i worked with an old 6.xx version of Drupal quite a while.
Now, i set up a 7.36 version of Drupal and build everything new. This works fine so far, but there is something i cant find an answer to:

I added a soundclound file field to a content type. I can edit this field, no problem. Now, i discovered that the field is not shown on the given content page, but it is shown in the "trimmed" Preview (not in the Preview full version) after editing. Maybe this is totally easy to solve, but i cant figure it out. 
Any suggestions how to have it on the full content page? Any help is very appreciated.

Regards, 
Stephan

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I had to configure at structure -> content type -> given page type -> manage display -> ful content to give the soundcloud file the player value and a weight of 1. 
Then i worked.